# Php to Rails - Rails Associations - contact_to_groups table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I have CRUD in place for creating contacts and creating groups. Both are nested under the user model.

I need to know how I can now associate contacts with groups.

I would like in my contact form to have some checkboxes (using formtastic) so the user can select which group(s) the contact belongs to.

In php i would make a table called contacts_to_groups and i would have contact_id & group_id columns, then when I would save the contact i would pass that data and use a join to get it back out later.

Thanks!

contact create form

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@contact.user, @contact] do |f| %>
<% f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :firstname, :label => 'First Name' %>
    <%= f.input :lastname, :label => 'Last Name' %>
    <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Email' %>

    <%= f.input :notes, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 10, :cols => 50, :maxlength => 10  }, :label => 'Notes' %>
<% end %>


<%= f.buttons %>
```

<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your models like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts  
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

And then you need to create table in DB contacts_groups(contact_id, group_id)

Comment: Thank you, i have 2 questions though. 1 - what would be the proper way to add that table. Through a migration? 2 - What would my contact create form now look like? Currently it looks like... (check my edit above)

Comment: I think the proper way to add that table is to use migrations. In the form you can output miltiselect field with groups titles or checkboxes field for all the groups using #each (didnt use formtastic yet, so dont know how it should be done)

Comment: Just add <%= f.input :groups, :label => 'Groups' %> inside your <% f.inputs do %> block.

Comment: That is amazing, Its working perfectly, thank you so much. It's very hard sometimes to figure out what going on, it is almost magical. It works very well. Do you know difference between has_and_belongs_to_many VS has_many, through?

Comment: has_and_belongs_to_many is a many-to-many relation using non-model table to store relations, has_many :through uses medium model to store many-to-many relation. The simple example of has_many :through are models Blog (has many posts, has many comments through posts), Post (belongs to blog, has many comments), Comment (belongs to post).

Comment: Contacts and Groups are nested under users, and when i do the <%= f.input :groups, :label => 'Groups' %> it shows all groups. What would be the best way to get only the groups owned by the user? my groups table has id, title & user_id

Comment: and i am already capturing the group owner in the user_id of the groups table

Comment: Provide a :collection option for groups input, like this: f.input :groups, :label => 'Groups', :collection => @groups (where @groups is an array of objects already fetched by user_id)